# Action actuator: how to get the "frame property" go back to 1 when the animation ends

Tags: animation, game-engine, properties

I have an action actuator that plays an animation (in "play" mode) and stores the "frame property" in a property called "frame".
When the animation ends, I believe the "frame property" should go back to 1 (I've seen this behavior in some tutorials), but this does not happen. Why is that so?

[image]

Comment: do you want the action animation to be cyclic (loop forever) ?

Comment: No i just want the "frame property" to go back to 1 when the animation ends. It stops to 30 instead.

Comment: I don't know what the rest of your logic looks like , but won't something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KdRAK.png) works ?

Comment: I have a keyboard sensor instead of an always sensor that triggers the action actuator. So I might need to adapt this a little. Anyway I'm quite sure a workaround exists. Nevertheless I would like to know if this is normal behavior or I'm the only one facing this problem. Thx

Comment: as far as I know , the action actuator can only read the value of frame property and can't modify it since it's a read only access. hopefully someone smarter than me will chime in with a solution.

Comment: You can also do the opposite.The action actuator sets the "frame" property to the current "frame" value of the animation being played.

Comment: Why should the property should automatically be set to zero? It shows what frame was played. The animation ends with the last frame, therefore the property shows the last frame. (if the last frame is zero it will show zero). So it works as I expect it to work. My question is: why do you want the property to be zero?

Comment: It doesn't 'have' to, but I've seen this behavior before (the property goes back to zero (or one) even if the animation ends with frame 30). The reason why I want this, is to check if the animation is finished. It is more convenient to check if the property is back to one (or zero) rather than "some other value" that may change during the design process. Anyway, is it possible to make the last frame of the animation to be one (or zero) without the suggested workarounds?

Comment: Better use the actuator sensor to measure when the action actuator deactivates itself. Check this one: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39456/can-i-use-blender-game-engine-bge-to-create-a-simple-interative-movie/39676#39676

Answer (score 0):

Similar to R00ts suggestion, the following workaround achieves what you are aiming for. Once an animation is finished, it plays it again, but with the end frame set to zero, effectively resetting the animation to its start. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Makes sense. Still, i would like to know if "not going back to frame one" at the end of the animation is to be considered standard behavior or it's rather a bug...